# Roots of a function with 5 variables by code

Tags: python, function, optimization, solver

**Function** : (((a+b-c+10-d)/2)-((3/2)*((((a-c)*(a-c))/(a+e-c))+(((b-d)*(b-d))/(b+10-e-d)))))
**Objective** : Function = 0, find roots.
**Constraints** :   b < a , d < c , e < c , b < e , d > a
**Bounds** :

```
0 < b < 10  
0 < c < 10  
0 < d < 10  
0 < e < 10
```

I initially coded 5 nested loops in python iterating from 0 to 10 with 0.1 steps but I couldn't see the program finishing any time after waiting 5 hours, I then tried using sympy's solve but only got equations consisting of symbols which was of no use to me. I have looked at scipy's fsolve but it absolutely makes no sense to me a there are so many options. The two main problems I face are : the time constraints/problem size and that most solvers don't allow you to enter constraints or boundaries.

I would really appreciate any help in solving this.

Comment: I suggest you to post your existing efforts so that we can comment on them.

Comment: The things I have done are extremely self-explanatory. The things I face - when using nested loops there is a huge number of iterations which god knows when it'll complete and the second is when using solvers i don't know how to insert contraints and neither do I know all the parameters that I should include.